# Counting the number of times you saw a symbol

Tags: ruby, regex

I was wondering how I would count the number of times something showed up, for example if I wanted to count the number of times the `#` showed up. Meaning if the string was,

```
H#i thank#s for the hel#p
```

Then it would become: `h1i thank2s for the hel3p`.

I know it's easy to check for a `#` in it. But the part that I'm hung up on is knowing how to do the basic math to get the numbers. Sorry is this is a dumb question and thank you for your help!

Comment: @Yuki suggested the best solution, but for practice you could also try this.  First convert the string to an array of characters, using [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split) or [String#chars](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-chars) (or to an enumerator using [String#each_char](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-each_char)). Do your replacements on the array elements `'#'` and then use [Array#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-join) to re-form the string.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yuki's answer is not at all the best solution. Defining a counter outside of the iteration is non-Rubyistic. Incrementing it manually is ugly. A much better solution would be using `with_index(1)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland then where's your answer?

Comment: @sawa, I cannot disagree. Yuki, I was just suggesting an exercise to illustrate that Ruby offers many ways to do this. I wouldn't recommend it in practice.  Since we are just giving hints here, a comment was sufficient.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: sorry, you're absolutely right, and my comment was meant to be directed at sawa, whose attitude is really grating me. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)'s `gsub(pattern) {|match| block } → new_str` signature, which lets you run a given piece of code (the block) to produce a different replacement for every match.

Use a counter declared outside the call to `gsub`, and increment it in the block, returning the newly incremented value.

Comment: Beat me by couple of seconds :D

Comment: @Amadan: :)! I preferred not to give the solution outright to what appears to be a homework question, but ah well.

Comment: Downvoter: honestly? "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."